# SVG format converting or suggestion

Tags: android, svg, android-canvas, vector-graphics, inkscape

Pictures I was trying to draw on a canvas have come up blank using the library SVG-android-1.1 and SVG images created in Inkscape. Is there some other SVG image editor I should be using?

Here I have the inkscape svg I created. It is filled with inkscape metadata as i've discovered.

http://pastebin.com/Y36pY75X

This is output from Android, clearly saying that it doesn't recognize inkscapes format.

```
05-06 13:26:45.647: D/SVGAndroid(7819): UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: Work
05-06 13:26:45.647: D/SVGAndroid(7819): UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: format
05-06 13:26:45.647: D/SVGAndroid(7819): UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: type
05-06 13:26:45.647: D/SVGAndroid(7819): UNRECOGNIZED SVG COMMAND: title
```

How do I convert the Inkscape SVG files to those that would be useful for SVGAndroid?

library being used: 
http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/downloads/detail?name=svg-android-1.1.jar

Comment: Have you read [Inkscape SVG vs. Plain SVG](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Inkscape#Inkscape_SVG_vs._Plain_SVG)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try my SVG rendering library, [AndroidSVG](http://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/), which does support Inkscape files.

If it doesn't correctly render your files, file a bug and I'll fix it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this applications directly online at www.janvas.com

I have tested it and works well on iOS and android

I hope that can be help for you.